# Simple construction of bump functions by smoothing/damping standard functions?

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

Define a bump function to be a smooth (infinitely differentiable / $C^\infty$) function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ with finite support. Preferably, support on some interval $(l, r)$. The only example of a bump function I know is this:

$$
f(x) \equiv \begin{cases}
\exp(-1/(1 - x^2)) & x \in (-1, 1) \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

However, I feel that there *must* be a simpler way to do this. Here are two ideas:

##### A. Smoothing out a continuous function

1. Take a continuous function to smooth out, such as $f(x) = max(0, 1 - |x|)$ ([desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nz6yposord)):

[image]

2. "smooth it out" by some procedure, which takes this continuous function and makes it smooth.

##### B. Damping the Gaussian

1. Start with the gaussian, which is smooth but has infinite support.
2. Do something to "kill" the value of the gaussian outside of a finite region, say $(-10,10)$ in a smooth way.

##### Questions

- Can **A** and **B** be made to work?
- If not, is there some proof that it's *impossible* to construct bump functions using the above ideas?

Comment: What would count for you as simpler? That standard example uses just the well known exponential function. Would you prefer "some procedure" that calls for  an explicit limiting process?

Comment: @EthanBolker I find that I naturally think of procedures A and B, but I need a minute to think how to construct the explicit version. Hence a request for a (potentially) more complicated construction, but with a key idea I find more natural.

Comment: One of the main uses of bump functions is for smoothing procedures. You replace your integrable function $f(x)$ with a function $\tilde{f}(x):=\int_{B_r(0)}h_r(y)f(x+y)\,dy$, where $h_r$ is a smooth bump function equal to 0 outside a small metric ball $B_r(0)$. I'm not aware of any other good smoothing procedures which send locally supported functions to locally supported functions.

Comment: With $f_0=(1-|x|)1_{|x|< 1}$, $f_{n+1} = f_n \ast 2^n 1_{|x|<1/2^{n-1}}$ then $f_\infty$ is likely $C^\infty_c$ but the proof may not be immediate.